# How to translate custom labels into other(sweedish, german,.......) languages?

Tags: customlabel

I have an issue with translation of custom labels...
 How to translate custom labels into other(sweedish, german,.......) languages.. Default language for my org is ENG.

How to get the translation text for custom labels??
For Ex: i have one custom label  **Online Help** ... how to translate these custom label into german?????

Any one can help me how to translate????

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you need to add the extra language to the Translation Workbench, as described in the comment posted by @Keith C

If you have added the additional languages you can add the custom label translations on the custom label page itself.

Here's the SF help text on translating custom labels:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_translate_edit.htm&language=en_US